# Convert JSON to JavaScript Object of Type X

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I know all about JSON.stringify or JSON.parse in the sense that one serializes an object and one deserializes the string back into an object. This is great!

However, I have the following situation:

```
var i = new MyMagicalObject();
var oi = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(i));
console.log(i.numFields()); // this is fine
console.log(oi.numFields()); // this throws since Object has no method 'numFields'
```

Basically, I'd like to treat oi as an instance of "MyMagicalObject" since that's what it is.

I'm sure there's some magic about setting the prototype on oi or something, but I'm fairly new to JavaScript. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem could be easily solved by redesigning your `MyMagicalObject` class. Here is an example of JSON-friendly class:

```js
function MyMagicalObject(props) {
  this.props = props || {};
}

MyMagicalObject.prototype.get = function(key) {
  return this.props[key];
};

MyMagicalObject.prototype.set = function(key, val) {
  this.props[key] = val;
  return this;
};

MyMagicalObject.prototype.toJSON = function() {
  return this.props;
};

MyMagicalObject.prototype.numFields = function() {
  return Object.keys(this.props).length;
};
```

This realization follows two rules:

1. It's constructor accepts JSON representation as a first argument.
2. It provides `toJSON` method to tell JS engine how to convert its instance to JSON.

Check the following example:

```
var obj = new MyMagicalObject();
obj.set('foo', 42).set('bar', 'baz');
alert(obj.numFields()); // 2

var str = JSON.stringify(obj);

var obj2 = new MyMagicalObject(JSON.parse(str));
alert(obj2.numFields()); // 2
```

Comment: I like this -- it feels more elegant than just copying the properties from the object literal to the instance of my object. Thanks.

Comment: what if you have storred a function in one of the props?

Comment: @Zim84 Don't. I realize that's a bit of a pithy response, but props -- by definition -- are properties, not functions, and you can't stream functions via JSON anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can't "store" JavaScript functions in JSON strings.

The only data types that can be stored in JSON are:

> - Number
> - String
> - Boolean
> - Array
> - Object
> - null

[(source)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types.2C_syntax_and_example)

Anything that isn't one of those types, gets ignored:

```js
function Test(){
    this.foo = function(){
        return 'bar';
    }
    this.theAnswer = '42';
}
var t = new Test();
alert(t.foo());
alert(JSON.stringify(t))
```

Comment: Yeah - I'm not looking to store a function in the JSON string. All I want to do is deserialize the object back INTO my object type.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new `MyMagicalObject()` and then overwrite its properties with the one from oi.

```
var t = new MyMagicalObject();
for(var k in oi) t[k]=oi[k];
```

That should do the trick. If you have a more complex object (with more than 1 dimension), search for a copy function that deep copies all properties.

Comment: I was hoping there was something more performant and less O(n)-ish, since I've already got the object?

Comment: The "more performant" thing to do would be to just create a new `MyMagicalObject`, passing the parsed object, and setting the values from it.

Answer (score 0):

Add `oi.prototype = MyMagicalObject.prototype;` after line 3.

or

create a new object and copy the properties:

```
var oi2 = new MyMagicalObject();
for (var p in oi) {
    if (oi.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
        oi2[p] = oi[p]
    }
}
console.log(oi2.numFields());
```

Comment: That didn't actually work. I already tried that -- that still throws a TypeError (has no method 'numFields').